# Как получить значение массива json в PHP по ключу

Tags: php, массивы, объекты

Только изучаю PHP и у меня возник вопрос, на который я как-то не особо нашел ответ...пробовал понять и сделать сам, но пока тщетно.

В общем есть file.json, в этом файле есть имя Rosales Donaldson, мне же нужно получить айди все, у кого он есть в друзьях.

Я сделал часть сам, которой смог открыть файл в php:

```
<?php
$link = file_get_contents("file:///C:/Users/Naravinger/Desktop/file.json");
$decode = json_decode($link);
$keySearch = array_column($decode, "friends", "name");
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($keySearch);
```

получил такую картину:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот как выглядит ячейка, где я нашел его имя в друзьях. Получается что есть он только в друзьях у одного человека.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот именно _id  "6055278b4894c854b6922dde" этот айди я должен получить по его имени.

Я буду рад просто подсказке, через что я могу получить этот id, так как все же я хотел бы сам попробовать сделать. И насколько я понимаю, я должен подучить ООП для выполнения данного задания?

Comment: ООП тут при чем?. `json_decode($link)` => `json_decode($link, 1)` и будет массив, дальше обычный обход массива с поиском в нужном месте имени, если нашли имя - возвращаем id

Comment: Про ООП подумал, так как это получается объект с классами? И да, я не утверждал, что тут нужно применять знания ООП, а просто уточнил так ли это. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, как я решил данное задание!

```
<?php
$link = file_get_contents("file:///C:/Users/Naravinger/Desktop/file.json");
$decode = json_decode($link, 1);

foreach ($decode as $id) {
    foreach ($id["friends"] as $id_friends) {
        if ($id_friends["name"] == "Rosales Donaldson") {
            echo $id["_id"];
        }
    }
}
```